# Moving existing GitHub issue to a GitHub Project board

Tags: github

We can convert a Note in GitHub project into a GitHub issue.

But how can I add an existing GitHub issue into the GitHub Project board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a button called "Add cards" where you can search using regular github filters and add any existing github issues to your board.

[image: Add card button]